# Rails Query a List for a CRON Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I'm a complete novice with CRON jobs but I think I have that set up correctly.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is send an email every day at 8:00 am to users (and a couple others) that have not logged in within the last 3 days, have not received the email, AND are marked as active OR temp as a status.

So from querying the db in console I know that I can do:

- first = User.where(status: 'active').or(User.where(status: 'temp'))
- second = first.where("last_login_at < ? ", Time.now-3.days)
- third = second.where(notified: false)

That's not certainly clean but I was struggling with finding a contained query that grabbed all that data. **Is there a cleaner way to do this query?**

I believe I have my cron job set up correctly using a runner. I have whenever installed and in my schedule.rb I have:

```
every 1.day, at: '8:00 am' do
 runner 'ReminderMailer.agent_mailer.deliver'
end
```

So under app > mailer I created ReminderMailer

```
class ReminderMailer < ApplicationMailer
 helper ReminderHelper

 def agent_reminder(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: email_recipients(user), subject: 'This is your reminder')
 end

 def email_recipients(agent)
  email_address = ''
  email_addresses += agent.notification_emails + ',' if agent.notification_emails
  email_addresses += agent.manager
  email_address += agent.email
 end
end
```

Where I'm actually struggling is where I should put my queries to send to the mailer, which is why I built a ReminderHelper.

```
module ReminderHelper

 def applicable_agents(user)
  agent = []
  first = User.where(status: 'active').or(User.where(status: 'temp'))
  second = first.where("last_login_at < ? ", Time.now-3.days)
  third = second.where(notified: false)
  agent << third
  return agent
 end
end
```

EDIT: So I know I could in theory do a chain of where queries. There's gotta be a better way right?

So what I need help on is: do I have the right structure in place? Is there a cleaner way to query this data in ActiveRecord for the CRON job? Is there a way to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining them together as if understand the conditions correct

- Have not logged in within the last 3 days,
- Have not received the email
- Are marked as active OR temp as a status

```
User.where("last_login_at < ? ", 3.days.ago).
     where(notified: false).
     where(status: ['active', temp])
```

```
module ReminderHelper
 def applicable_agents(user)
   User.where("last_login_at < ? ", 3.days.ago).
     where(notified: false).
     where(status: ['active', temp])
 end
end
```

You don't need to add/ assign them to array. Because this relation is already like an array. You can use `.to_a` if you need array. If you just want to iterate over them then `users.each` should work fine.

***Update***

```
class User

    scope :not_notified, -> { where(notified: false) }
    scope :active_or_temp, -> { where(status: ['active', 'temmp']) }
    scope :last_login_in, -> (default_days = 3) { where("last_login_at < ?", default_days.days.ago) }

end
```

and then use

```
    User.not_notified.active_or_temp.last_login_in(3)
```

Instead of `Time.now-3.days` it's better to use `3.days.ago` because it keeps time zone also in consideration and avoids unnecessary troubles and failing test cases.

Additionally you can create small small scopes and combine them. More read on scopes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: There's a SyntaxError: unexpected ', ', expecting => "last_login_at < ?", 3.days.ago. But I guess I can just chain it.

Comment: `User.where("last_login_at < ? ", 3.days.ago).where(notified: false).where(status: ['active', temp])` try this

Comment: I'm ending up with User.where(status: ["active", "temp"], notified: false).where("last_login_at < ? ", 3.days.ago).

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: I was actually looking at using scopes not that long ago. Except when I try running it I end up with undefined method on the first scope present. Plus I still have to figure out a couple other queries involving some other tables that I'm wrapping my head around.

Comment: Then I would suggest post question with scope issue and close this one.